# php simplexml append instead of updating

Tags: php, simplexml

I try to update a existing xml file and then save it using the same name, but it append instead of updating. Also the Swedish characters like Ä are transformed to unicode, can that be prevented by specify encoding?

```
  $folderPath = dirname(__DIR__). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;   // website/
  $fileName = 'event.xml';
  $destFile = $folderPath .$fileName; // website/event.xml

  $xml = simplexml_load_file($destFile);

  //Update
  $xml->events->event->title = $eventTitle;
  $xml->events->event->eventdate = $eventDate;

  // save the updated document
  $xml->asXML($destFile);
```

so I end up with a xml like this (which isn't even valid xml)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<events>
 <event>
    <title>&#xC4;</title>
    <eventdate>2019-12-01</eventdate>
 </event>
<events><event><title>&#xC4;</title><eventdate>2019.12.01</eventdate></event></events></events>
```

when I need it to be like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<events>
 <event>
    <title>Å</title>
    <eventdate>2019-12-01</eventdate>
 </event>
</events>
```

Comment: Sorry but that still append the same way as before...?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the XML. Anyway, I feel it's a bit suspicious that XML would contain only one event, because its format indicates a list of events. You only want to update the first one then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to change, the first would be to enable UTF-8 in the XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The second is that when you load data using SimpleXML, the variable *is* the root element, so `$xml` is `<events>`.  So you don't need to use that in your levels...

```
$xml->event->title = $eventTitle;
$xml->event->eventdate = $eventDate;
```

Also, just to say *(wich isnt even valid xml)* - it is, may not be what you are after but it's still valid XML.